# How to set recyclerview grid according to screen height android?

Tags: android

I have an app in which I have a recycled view with custom layout what I want I want to show item according to device height. If the device is large then I have to show items with 1 grid or device height is medium then want to show 2 grid.

code:-

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
```

Code of recyclerview

```
rightPaneAdapter = new SidePanelListAdapter(UserListingMainActivity.this, models, this);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 1);
    mOptionList.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mOptionList.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    mOptionList.setAdapter(rightPaneAdapter);
```

Comment: use grid `autofit` and make grid `wrap_content`.

Comment: few code plsssss.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    ((Activity) context).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);

    int devicewidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels / 3;

    int deviceheight = displaymetrics.heightPixels / 4;

    holder.image_view.getLayoutParams().width = devicewidth;

    //if you need same height as width you can set devicewidth in holder.image_view.getLayoutParams().height
    holder.image_view.getLayoutParams().height = deviceheight;
```